# Regular expression end string with first comma

Tags: regex

I need some help with regular expression:

Input:

```
0;-8.04,-8.22,-8.30
0;-8.04
```

I would like the output to be

```
-8.04
-8.04
```

I did make it work for both strings separately, but not so that I could feed my function with each of them and still get the same result.

Thanks for you help

Comment: So instead of showing us your attempts so that we could help fix them, you'd rather just we hand you solution directly?

Comment: This url gives an example of checking for valid email addresses. It illustrates exactly what each part of the regex does. It would be extremely easy to tailor to your problem: [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/regexbuddy/email.html)

Comment: What language or system will this be used in?

Comment: It is going to be used in python, the system is classified..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=;)-?\d+\.\d+
```

([**demo**](http://rubular.com/r/mOnvs8r4MP))

Comment: Which is not available in JS though :)

Comment: @mishik Lookarounds are fairly standard. If the OP indicates that he is using JS I will change this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention language. An example in JavaScript:

```
your_string.match(";(-?[0-9.]+),?")[1]
```

Example:

```
> "0;-8.04,-8.22,-8.30".match(";(-?[0-9.]+),?")[1]
"-8.04"
```

Comment: This won't match lines that do not end with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
.*?;\s*([^,]*)(,|$).*
```

It captures anything after a semicolon and before the next comma or end of line. Example: http://www.regex101.com/r/bE7oI9